# Users at remote location cannot run executable on file share

Tags: windows, installation, network-share, microsoft-office

Got a bit of a headscratcher here

We have our installer for Office 2016 located on a Synology NAS. When accessing the installer on the share (i.e. \\servername\installs\office2016\setup.exe) from within our main office, it launches without issue. When we try to do so at our remote location across town (which is connected via VPN and is behind a Sonicwall firewall) we get the following error:

[image]

This is regardless of whether we use the 32-bit or 64-bit installer for Office, and regardless of whether the system we are trying to install it on has 32-bit or 64-bit Windows. Copying the installer locally from the share lets it run without issue.

Any ideas as to why it won't run from the share, but it works without issue with the exact same files when they're copied to the local computer?

Comment: If you lookup in the property tab, those this files are tagged dangerous, aka display an *unblock* option ? If yes let me know, you can unblock them all to be sure no security setting block you

Comment: have you tried to assign a drive letter to your share? sometimes those installers are not fully designet do be deployed via network